# jQuery Sexy Combo wrapper height problem

Tags: jquery

I have a height problem with Sexy Combo ( google 'Sexy Combo' ), a jQuery editable drop-down list.

The author of the script didn't optimized the drop-down to look good if it is placed in a popup which is not visible on page load. After loading the popup and clicking on the drop-down, the list doesn't show -- FireBug says it's height is 0px.

I was reading the script but I couldn't find how to make the list-wrapper with fixed height.
If someone would like to help, this is the Sexy Combo [**script**](http://brownfolder.com/project/jquery.sexy-combo.js).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you've fixed it please delete the question or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed... I've changed the pop-up property from `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`.